# Modify RPM package to remove dependencies

Tags: package-management, rpm, packaging, distributions, packagekit

tl;dr:

We build an RPM package that automatically detect dependencies (no `Requires` in `.spec` file). How can I remove dependencies from this RPM package.

Long story:->
I'm shipping the dynamic libraries along with the binary but RPMs automatic dependencies mechanism obviously lists that shipped libraries also as dependencies. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I you don't want rpm to process these dependencies automatically; you can use:

```
AutoReqProv: no
```

However, I have multiple time packaged myself binaries and the libraries they depend on; rpm has never caused me any trouble in that way; maybe your way of packaging is not optimal?

For further reading on the automatic dependencies: http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

Comment: Ok let me ask you this, after you package the said libraries and create RPM; does `rpm -qp --requires <yourPackage>` shows the packaged libraries listed there? If yes, then thats what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

These dependencies that are listed in `rpm -qp -requires <pkg>.rpm` are *[virtual packages](http://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html)* if [automatic dependencies](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html) is specified in `<pkg>.spec` file. These virtual packages are NOT library `soname` but rather just virtual package names (even though they look like `soname`).

e.g. on Fedora 27, this works

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides "libQt5Core.so.5()(64bit)"        
qt5-qtbase-5.9.2-5.fc27.x86_64
```

but this doesn't

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides libQt5Core.so.5
no package provides libQt5Core.so.5
$ rpm -q --whatprovides libQt5Core
no package provides libQt5Core
$ rpm -q --whatprovides Qt5Core
no package provides Qt5Core
```

If your own `<pkg>.rpm` itself bundles the libraries (i.e. provides these virtual packages) then RPM will not complain if these virtual packages are not installed on the system since they are supplied with your package.